how to display serial number in sql
How to display the serial number for the below
select count(*) toatl_count, "employee is Invalid" error from emp
union
select count(*) total_count, "comapny name is incorrect" error from company;

result will be
total_count error
10          employee is Invalid
55          comapny name is incorrect

but I need output as below
serial number total_count error
     1         10          employee is Invalid
     2        55          comapny name is incorrect


Add 1 to first select, and 2 to second select. Or take the unions result and use ROW_NUMBER() to get numbering,

BTW, are you really using Oracle (PL/SQL)? Double quotes are used to delimit identifiers, i.e. "employee is Invalid" is a column name, not a string. Use single quotes for strings, e.g. 'Some text'.

sorry single quotes.. type mistake

Then you can edit your question.

Yep, correct the wrong quotes. And correct the wrong tags. This is not about Oracle's programming language PL/SQL. Is this even an Oracle database? And why use UNION [DISTINCT] when there are obviously no rows to remove? Use UNION ALL instead. And please explain why 'employee is Invalid' gets serial number 1. Is it always 1 for this error? Or is it because the total count is lower than for 'comapny name is incorrect'? Or does yet some other rule apply? And do you want your result ordered? So far it is left to chance, which of the two lines comes first in the results.

Try this:
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS serial_no,
  total_count, 
  error
FROM (
  SELECT count(*) total_count, '"employee is Invalid"' error FROM emp
  UNION
  SELECT count(*) total_count, '"company name is incorrect"' error FROM company
) subquery
ORDER BY serial_no;

